# GNOME: Change workspace with arrow keys on overview?

Tags: gnome

When in the GNOME (45) overview, using the arrow keys selects windows. However, I never use that feature, and wanted to change the functionality so that if I press left/right arrow keys in the overview it switches workspace instead to make that simpler and quicker.

I couldn't find a shortcut nor extension for this, so is this possible at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with the arrows is moving the focus/highlight to a different window.

While [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) allows us to change most keybindings, it's not possible, to my knowledge, to change this particular highlight behavior (without altering the source code).

That being said that are more ways to change workspaces easily and one of them might work for you.

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (switch to workspace on the left)
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> (switch to workspace on the right)

You can also [change this to any shortcut you want using dconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099107) Although you might want to check under Gnome Settings/Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts which offers a more user friendly UI.

- Hitting <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> while in Activities Overview.
- Scrolling through the new [Activities Indicator](https://release.gnome.org/45/#activities-indicator) in Gnome 45.